# VBA Excel on Mac: Print / Export to PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I have this huge excel file with macros, it works perfectly on windows, but on MacOs it gives me an error 1004. Can somebody help me to translate following code so that it works on Macos? Or actually, can somebody translate it to work on Excel (Macos), because I have absolute no understanding of coding. If somebody can help me with this, I don't have to install Windows to my Mac :)

```
Sub SaveAsPdf(train)
    'On Error Resume Next
    'Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Activate

    Application.Goto reference:="date"
    days = Year(ActiveCell.Value) & Month(ActiveCell.Value) & Day(ActiveCell.Value)

    Application.Goto reference:="path"
    Path = ActiveCell.Value
    If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then
        Path = Path & "\"
    End If

    ws = "Train " & train & " Production schedule"

    Sheets(ws).Select
    Time_Stamp = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd_HhNn")

    TNimi = Path & ws & Time_Stamp & ".pdf"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    TNimi, Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

    ws = "General Schedule " & train
    fname = "General Schedule Train " & train
    Sheets(ws).Select
    Time_Stamp = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd_HhNn")

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    Path & fname & "_" & Time_Stamp & ".pdf", Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Sheets("Break Plan Input").Select
End Sub

Sub SaveQSheet(train)
    Sheets("Break Plan Input").Select
    Application.Goto reference:="date"
    days = Year(ActiveCell.Value) & Month(ActiveCell.Value) & Day(ActiveCell.Value)

    Application.Goto reference:="path"
    Path = ActiveCell.Value
    If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then
        Path = Path & "\"
    End If
    Time_Stamp = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd_HhNn")
    Sheets("Inspection and Sold Info").Select
    Sheets("Inspection and Sold Info").Copy
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & "Train " & train & " Inspection and Sold Info " & Time_Stamp & ".xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Sheets("Break Plan Input").Select
End Sub
```

[Path defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziogH.png)

Comment: How have you defined the "path" ? The method is not identical between pc and mac... It may help to show more of your code...

Comment: Hi Mike, I edited my post with more code and link to screenshot which shows how path is defined. Hope that there is all the info needed. TNimi = TName